# How to combine 10 NLP preprocessing regexes?

Tags: python, nlp, dask

Here are all the things I want to do to a Pandas dataframe in one pass in python:

1. Lowercase text
2. Remove whitespace
3. Remove numbers
4. Remove special characters
5. Remove emails
6. Remove stop words
7. Remove NAN
8. Remove weblinks
9. Expand contractions (if possible not necessary)
10. Tokenize

I am using Dask to parallelize my Python dataframe functions.

Here's an example function:

```
df2 = df.map_partitions(lambda d: d.replace(r'\t|\r|\n', '', regex=True))
```

However, I have one of the above functions for all of the above preprocessing steps I am trying to do. Is there a way to combine all the regexes? I consider using or pipes, but I don't know if that's the optimal solution.

Comment: have you tried wrapping all of those steps in one function - then call the function in your map_partition?

Comment: ^ second @AmirhosImani 's suggestion

Comment: @AmirhosImani I have not!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a sklearn transformer that does all that for you.

E.g.

```
import re
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin


class TextCleaner(TransformerMixin):
    '''
    Text cleaner example 
    '''

    def __init__(self,
                                                        words_only=False,
                                                        emoji_normalize=False,
                                                        remove_digits=True,
                                                        lower_case=False,
                                                        stop_words = None,
                                                        token=False):

        self.words_only = words_only
        self.word_normalize = word_normalize
        self.emoji_normalize = emoji_normalize
        self.remove_digits = remove_digits
        self.lower_case = lower_case
        self.stop_words = stop_words
        self.token = token

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        self.X = X

        # eyes [nose] mouth | mouth [nose] eyes pattern
        emoticons = r"(?:[<>]?[:;=8][\-o\*\']?[\)\]\(\[dDpP/\:\}\{@\|\\]|[\)\]\(\[dDpP/\:\}\{@\|\\][\-o\*\']?[:;=8][<>]?)"
        emoticon_re = re.compile(emoticons, re.VERBOSE | re.I | re.UNICODE)

        # Keep word only. Digit are consider true Emojis false
        if self.words_only:
            clean_text = self.X.apply(lambda x: (re.sub('[\W]+', ' ', x)))
        else:
            clean_text = self.X.apply(lambda x: ('{}{}'.format(re.sub('[\W]+', ' ', x),
                                                                    ''.join(re.findall(emoticon_re, x)))))

        # normalize emoji?
        if self.emoji_normalize:

            clean_text = self.X.apply( lambda x:
                                                                            (re.sub('[\W]+', ' ', x) +
                                                                                                    ' '.join(re.findall(emoticon_re, x)).replace(';',':').replace('-',''))
                                                                            )

        if self.remove_digits:
            clean_text = clean_text.apply(
                lambda x: x.translate(str.maketrans('', '', '0123456789')))

        if self.lower_case:
            clean_text = clean_text.str.lower()

        # list of stop words    
        if self.stop_words is not None:

            _ = [word for word in clean_text.split() if word not in stop_words]

            clean_text = ' '.join(word for word in _)

        if self.token:
            return clean_text.str.split()
        else:
            return clean_text
```

You can the chain this transformer with other transformers and your classifier. E.g.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

word_vec_para = dict(
    ngram_range=(1, 2),
    tokenizer=token,
    lowercase=True,
    min_df=1)

pipe = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('text_clean', TextCleaner(
            remove_digits=True, lower_case=True, stop_words=your_stop_words)),
     ('word_vec', CountVectorizer(**word_vec_para)),
     ('word_tdf', TfidfTransformer(sublinear_tf=True)), ('fe_se', SelectKBest(chi2, k='all')),
    ('log_reg', LogisticRegression(verbose=1))])

pipe.fit(X,y)
```